# How should i proceed with malloc on a struct with ints after string values?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, c-strings

I wrote this simple user struct:

```
typedef struct {
char login[20];
char password;
int privArm;
int privNav;
int privCom;
}User;
```

On main, i want to create multiple users using pointers (i want to send them to other functions later), so for that i wrote this malloc:

```
User *newUsrPtr;
newUsrPtr = (User*) malloc(n * sizeof(User));
```

Then, i ask the user to input the values in *newUsrPtr varibles. This is where my problem lies:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    printf("\nInsert user name: ");
    if (fgets(((newUsrPtr+i)->login), sizeof(User), stdin) == NULL) {
        // Error
        exit(1);
    } printf("%s", (newUsrPtr+i)->login);

    printf("\nInsert password: ");
    if (fgets(((newUsrPtr+i)->password), sizeof(User), stdin) == NULL) {
        // Error
        exit(1);
    };printf("%s", &(newUsrPtr+i)->password);

    printf("\Insert privilege 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &(newUsrPtr+i)->privArm);printf("%d", &(newUsrPtr+i)->privArm);

    printf("\nInsert privilege 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &(newUsrPtr+i)->privCom);printf("%d", &(newUsrPtr+i)->privCom);

    printf("\nInsert privilege 3: ");
    scanf("%d", &(newUsrPtr+i)->privNav);printf("%d", &(newUsrPtr+i)->privNav);

}
```

The problem is that the program "skips" the first input, and after inputting a value, it crashes with

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Full code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct {
        char login[20];
        char password;
        int privArm;
        int privNav;
        int privCom;
    }User;

 int main() {
    User *newUsrPtr;
    int n;

    printf("Insert how many users to be created: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    newUsrPtr = (User*) malloc(n * sizeof(User));

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("\nInsert user name: ");
        if (fgets(((newUsrPtr+i)->login), sizeof(User), stdin) == NULL) {
            // Error
            exit(1);
        } printf("%s", (newUsrPtr+i)->login);

        printf("\nInsert password: ");
       

 if (fgets(((newUsrPtr+i)->password), sizeof(User), stdin) == NULL) {

        // Error
        exit(1);
    };printf("%s", &(newUsrPtr+i)->password);

    printf("\nInsert privilege 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &(newUsrPtr+i)->privArm);printf("%d", &(newUsrPtr+i)->privArm);

    printf("\nInsert privilege 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &(newUsrPtr+i)->privCom);printf("%d", &(newUsrPtr+i)->privCom);

    printf("\nInsert privilege 3: ");
    scanf("%d", &(newUsrPtr+i)->privNav);printf("%d", &(newUsrPtr+i)->privNav);

}
system('pause');
return 0;
}
```

What is exactly my problem? How do i solve it? Where can i read more about this? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your password is just one character? `fgets` into a single `char` is *not going to happen*. Turn on more compiler warnings, as that should get flagged.

Comment: `(fgets(((newUsrPtr+i)->password), sizeof(User), stdin)` is just plain wrong. `sizeof` refers to the entire user record, not just the password string component. **Always specify the correct size of your buffers** or you will have catastrophic overflow bugs.

Comment: Tip: Instead of `(x+y)->z` use `x[y]->z`. Don't do pointer math if you can avoid it.

Comment: Tip: Instead of smashing around with pointer offsets at all, create a pointer to the record you're working on within that iteration of the loop and use that consistently. Like `User* user = newUsrPtr[i]` is one way to quickly alias it. Even better: Move that input code into a function that takes a `User*` argument.

Comment: Tip: Don't declare variables and then initialize them at some distant point in your code, collapse those two together. It's extremely important that any variables you use are initialized properly, so make that as abundantly clear as possible. Separating these two important bits of code makes that harder to verify. In other words: `int x = y` is clear, while `int x` then a bunch of code, then *possibly* `x = y`, is not.

Comment: @tadman — did you mean "Instead of `(x+y)->z`, use `x[y].z`"?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, that!